# Как перевести строку в вектор для расчёта евклидового расстояния?

Tags: python, vector, python-3.7

Есть проект по идентификации людей с помощью веб камеры. Проблема заключается в расчёте евклидового расстояния между дескрипторами лица. При извлечении дескрипторов, они с типом `dlib.vector`, мне их необходимо занести в файл (в перспективе создать БД), а затем извлечь для расчёта евклидового расстояния. Второй дескриптор получаю с камеры ноутбука. Использую 2 нейронки от dlib. Я могу извлечь дескриптор из файла, преобразовать его в массив, список, строку, но как я понял оба дескриптора должны иметь тип `dlib.vector`, что сделать мне не удаётся.

Python 3.6 + cv2 + dlib + scipy

Расчёт евклидового расстояния.
    a = distance.euclidean(face_descriptor1, face_descriptor2)

Comment: Код нужен, прикрепляйте. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Не забудте добавить код, а то уже есть голоса за закрытие вопроса.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проще всего воспользоваться модулем Numpy - сначала перевести dlib.vector в numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.asarray(dlib.vector)
```

Расчёт евклидового расстояния:

```
np.linalg.norm(database_landmarks - arr)
```

Comment: А что значит `are`?

Comment: @0xdb, это опечатка, спасибо что заметили! :)

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за ответ! Всё же смог сам справиться. Выяснил, что для такой конструкции`a = distance.euclidean(face_descriptor1, face_descriptor2)` не обязательно получить два вектора типа dlib.vector. Как я понял, нужен был двумерный массив, в котором всего один столбец и 128 строк. Справился так.

```
 import numpy as np
 line = []
 face_descriptor1 = np.zeros((128, 1))
 f = open("D:\sns findface\descript\descript"+ str(i) +".txt")
 for z in range(128):
     line = float(f.readline())
     face_descriptor1[z][0] = line
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по вашему ответу - основная сложность была в том, чтобы прочитать вектор `face_descriptor` из текстового файла, получив матрицу размерности `(128, 1)`.

Сделать это можно так:

```
face_descriptor1 = np.loadtxt(filename).reshape(-1, 1)
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/474252) Это лучше сделать апдейтом Вашего же ответа, либо комментарием к ответу автора, наверное.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Почему не является? ТС дал свой ответ, из него стала более ясна его задача.

Comment: @0xdb вчитайтесь в последнее предложение моего комментария. __Это лучше сделать апдейтом Вашего же ответа, либо комментарием к ответу автора, наверное.__ MaxU уже оставил хороший ответ, который принял автор вопроса. То, что есть в этом ответе, следует либо туда же как дополнительную информацию добавить, либо правку в ответ автора внести. Но это мое мнение.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Извините, когда начинаю читать шабонный коментарий из очереди проверок,то не дочитываю до конца:) Там есть пункт "Комментарий не нужен", чтобы оставить свой комментарий. Да, это ваше мнение, совпадёт оно с мнением других проверяющих, то ответ будет удалён и его автор перенесёт его содержимое в предыдущий ответ.